# Am I right about this exercise of Matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my book of *Linear Algebra* asks me the following exercise: For any square matrix $T$, over $\mathbb{R}$, it defines $p(T)$ to be the matrix $c_nT^n+\cdots + c_1T+I$ with $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i$, so prove that for **any** square matrix there is a polynomial such that $p(T)$ is the zero matrix.

But my question, is it true when $T=Z$? I think that not beacuse $c_iT^i=Z$, then $p(T)=I\ne Z$, where $Z$ is the zero matrix of appropriate size. Am I wrong?

Comment: Isn't it $\dotsc + c_0 I$?

Comment: what is $Z$? do you mean integer entry? I see you mean zero matrix. Then use just $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer No, I am sure that is only $I$. I think that autor's purpose is let $I$ only because otherwise we always have that $c_i=0$ for all $i$ will be the answer.

Comment: I think the book meant $T^n+c_1 T^{n-1}+\cdots c_nI$. Look up characteristic polynomial of a matrix.

Comment: In that case, a **necessary** condition is that $T$ be invertible.

Comment: What are the $c_n$?

Comment: Excuse me, $c_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The book is http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf, page 219, exercise 2.35-b. There is a prior item that suggests something similar.

Comment: There is a typo in the exercise; the author has $c_0 I$ in part a.

Comment: @user84413 in that case the answer will be trivial because if $c_i=0$ for all $i$ then $p(T)=Z$ always.

Comment: That's right; the equation is trivially satisfied if T is the zero matrix if the last term is changed.  (As you're observing, this shows the statement of the problem wasn't quite right.)

Comment: @DiegoHuerfano Definitely should have a $c_0I$. I'm sure the book is asking for non-trivial polynomials... (as in part (a)). So the answer should not be trivial (but still not too bad!)

Comment: OK, i get it, thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, wanted to give a simple hint. I noticed that in the book it had not covered eigenvalues yet, which would give immediate results from characteristic polynomials (minimal polynomials later tie to Jordan form)

Consider the list $(I,T,T^2,T^3,\ldots)$. These are elements of the vector space $M_{n}$ of all $n\times n$ matrices, which is finite dimensional.

Can you associate finding a $p(x)$ of degree $r$ such that $p(T)=0$ to a property concerning $(I,T,\ldots,T^r)$?